# Como consigo verificar a quantidade de numerais em uma lista na linguagem Python?

Tags: python

Preciso calcular a média dos itens da lista, e imaginei um código que captura a soma de todos os itens e divide pela quantidade presente na lista, porém travei na parte de adquirir a quantidade de números para usar na média arítimetica.

código que imaginei ->

```
#Calculo de média dos itens da lista

lista = [9, 7, 7, 10, 3, 9, 6, 6, 2]

somaItens = sum(lista)

quantidadeItens = ->???<-

media = somaItens / quantidadeItens

print(media)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adquirir a quantidade de itens em uma lista utilizando o método [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len). Lembrando que, sim, estamos consultando uma lista e a documentação aponta que o `len` retorna a propriedade `lenght` de um objeto, mas é importante lembrar da máxima de que "...em Python tudo é objeto".

O código a seguir executa a operação e previne casos nos quais você possa tentar dividir por zero e iniciar um processo de entropia acelerado do universo (rs):

```
#Calculo de média dos itens da lista

lista = [9, 7, 7, 10, 3, 9, 6, 6, 2]

media = sum(lista) / len(lista) if len(lista) > 0 else 0

print(media)
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, sou nova no mundo da programação,mas acho que posso te ajudar. Uma maneira seria o método **len**.
A função **len** serve para retornar o numero de caracteres de uma variável.

```
lista = [9, 7, 7, 10, 3, 9, 6, 6, 2]

somaItens = sum(lista)

quantidadeItens = len(lista)

media = somaItens / quantidadeItens

print(media)
```